# Mopub native ad

Tags: android, mopub

I am trying to implement mopub native ad in recycler view , I got success till getting test native ads, I tried disabling test order from mopub account but I am not able to get real ad on the device !

Please suggest what step I need to follow!

Any help will be really appreciated ! 
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Full instructions for integrating the ad networks can be found here:

> AdColony
>
> AdMob
>
> Chartboost
>
> Conversant
>
> Facebook Audience Network
>
> Millennial Media
>
> Tapjoy
>
> Vungle

use above ads, for more description refer below link  :https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Integrating-Third-Party-Ad-Networks